# Unity APK size much higher than Resources used in it?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, assets

I am working with unity 4.0 and my 2d game is almost completed, and ready to upload on Google Play Store. But the problem is that the APK size is very high. My total size of all Assets is 10.7 MB and the final APK size is 17.0 MB. So I can't understand how it happens.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The APK does not merely consist of the assets. The Unity player is compiled into the resulting APK and explains the size of the APK being larger than the pure assets alone.

Comment: Means that apk size is not only assets size but also there is some libraries like unity player it self.

Comment: This lib can't be removed

Comment: in the same APK you have the code too and other data.. it's normal

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) article in Unity's documentation.

You can reduce the size of the apk by doing:

- Reducing the size of textures and compressing it
- Reducing the poly count and compressing the meshes and animations
- Minimizing the use of external imports
- Using .NET subset when compiling